# How to generate Java from online UML models?

Tags: java, uml, modeling

I need to create UML class diagram online and to generate Java code from it.

Drawing tools such as cacoo don't allow to generate code as they are not real UML modelers.

Does anybody know an UML online tool that generates Java code?

Thanks for your help~~

Answer (score 8):

You should take a look at GenMyModel an [UML online tool](http://www.genmymodel.com/)

GenMyModel allows you to create an UML class diagram online and generate Java code from it.

Answer (score 1):

There is one generator that allows you to produce Java source code from a UML model. This module uses the standard UML2 metamodel provided by Eclipse Foundation and as such is compatible with any UML tools using this standard like the UML Designer. It's based on the award winning code generation project, Acceleo.

You can refer this:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uml-java-generator#.UeexrtJqkfA

Answer (score 1):

If you have the UML files(Class Diagram etc) you can import it into any of the UML diagram Tools(I prefer  ArgoUML). Then you will have option to generate the code from the UML diagrams. The code is not just java but multiple languages. Rest if for you to explore!