# UML To Java Conversion

Tags: java, uml

I'm starting to learn Java program, and need help converting these UML diagrams to Java:

```
SquareLocation
- x: int
- y: int
+ SquareLocation(void)
+ SquareLocation(int, int)
+ setSquareX(int): void
+ setSquareY(int): void
+ getSquareX(void): int
+ getSquareY(void): int
```

```
Square
- feature: AbstractFeature
- location: SquareLocation
+ Square(int, int, AbstractFeature)
+ setFeature(Feature): void
+ getFeature(void): AbstractFeature
+ getLocation(void): SquareLocation
```

```
AquaFeature extends AbstractFeature
+ aquaLifetime: static final int
+ AquaFeature(int)
+ AquaFeature(String)
```

```
AquaSystem extends AbstractSystem
+ aquaCost: static final int
+ aquaWorkersRequired: static final int
+ aquaInfluenceRange: static final int
- aquaFeatures: ArrayList
+ AquaSystem(ClaudiusModel)
+ addFeature(AbstractFeature): void
+ removeFeature(AbstractFeature): void
+ containsFeature(AbstractFeature): boolean
+ saveToFile(String): void
+ loadFromFile(String): void
+ reset(void): void
```

Comment: I think you can just type some code....

Comment: Please add the code you have create so we can correct it if necessary

Comment: I have to add a class file for this code

Comment: From the help center: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." Please don't just post your homework assignment. Stackoverflow is not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could Google for "class diagram", if that's what you have as UML. You might read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram). Basically if you have method like `+containsFeature(AbstractFeature): boolean` then you have the `+` identifying that the method is public, `containsFeature` as method Name with an `AbstractFeature` as Parameter and the return value is a `boolean`. But you definitively should read some UML specifications so you know what to do at which Point.

@Edit: Maybe [this](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html) helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

- SquareLocation
  -> This is the name of you class

> public class SquareLocation {

- x: int  -> This is an object variable of type int

> int x;

- y: int -> This is an object variable of type int

> int y;

- SquareLocation(void)  -> This is a constructor because it doesn't specify a return type and is has the same name as the class

> public SquareLocation() {}

- SquareLocation(int, int)  -> This is also an constructor which take 2 parameters of type int. Since we already have 2 object variable x and y of type int I suspect they should match.

> public SquareLocation(int paramX, int paramY) { x = paramX; y =
>   paramY; }

- setSquareX(int): void  -> This is a method which takes an int as parameter and return nothing.

> public void setSquareX(int parameter){
>   x = parameter;
>   }

- setSquareY(int): void -> This is a method which takes an int as parameter and return nothing.

> public void setSquareY(int parameter){
>   y = parameter;
>   }

- getSquareX(void): int  -> This is a method who returns an int

> public int getSquareX(){
>   return x;
>   }

- getSquareY(void): int -> This is a method who returns an int

> public int getSquareY(){
>   return y;
>   }

Answer (score 0):

There is a book that describes in detail how to convert UML into Java and reverse: [UML for Java™ Programmers](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=336264&seqNum=3). Obviously, some time you have to adopt some conventions. The link I've provided to you also explains the conversion between Java classes and UML class diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for you:

- Search on Internet for these terms: `uml to java code generator online`
- Check this SO question: [How to generate Java from online UML models?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17719159/363573)